# Is it possible to solve a differential equation with a user-defined variable mesh in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, mesh, finite-difference-method

For some differential equations, its solution may evolve to a cusp, for example, singular behavior. One may want to introduce additional mesh points near the cusp to accurately follow the solution throughout the formation of the local singularity.

**General question: Can we define a variable mesh scheme in `NDSolve` to solve a nonlinear PDE about $h(x,t)$ with finite difference method (FDM), in which the number of mesh points near a cusp may be determined by the value of the local minimum or maximum, $h_{min}$ or $h_{max}$.** Let us consider the case of a cusp having $h_{min}$. I noted that there are three additional processes should be added: (1) after each time step, a new set of mesh needs to be defined with additional points introduced; (2) the values of $h(x^{n+1}_j,t^{n+1})$ on the new mesh needs to be obtained from those $h(x^n_i,t^n)$ on the old mesh by interpolating; (3) the time step should also be adjusted according to increasing mesh resolution to ensure a consistent evolution in local mesh scales.

For example, consider the following PDE

$$h_t+(h^3h_{xxx}+h^{-1}h_x)_x=0,$$
which is defined on $x\in[0, L]$ with $L=8$, subject to the boundary conditions $h_x=h_{xxx}=0$ at the two end points of the interval. This equation will evolve a cusp at $x=0$ with a harmonic initial condition $h(x,0)=1-0.1\cos(2\pi x/L)$.

Pleas note that **I can solve this equation using `NDSolve` with Method of Line and some common settings**, which can be found easily on the site. However, to have more control on the numerical scheme and to obtain a more accurate solution especially near the singular point, I want to use the above mentioned variable mesh scheme, which begins with, say, $20$ points and increases to a much more dense mesh by $h_{min}=10^{-5}$. Specifically, is it possible to define a mesh in `NDSolve` with the following transformation $x(s)=h^2_{min}(t)\sinh(s)$, where $s(x,t)$ is the coordinate used in the numerical scheme. The mesh points are uniform in $s$ and thus the mesh spacing in $x$ is nearly uniform near $x=0$ but its spacing increases away from $x=0$. Please refer to the $\sinh$ curve.

[image]

After each time step, a new mesh is produced using the current value of $h_{min}(t^n)$ with additional mesh points introduced to keep the mesh spacing in $s$ roughly constant. The values of $h(x^{n+1}_j,t^{n+1})$ on the new mesh are obtained from those $h(x^n_i,t^n)$ on the old mesh by cubic interpolation, say. Also, the time step is chosen by

$$\Delta t=\Delta x_0^4/h^3_{min}\approx h_{min}^5 \Delta s^4,$$
where $\Delta x_0$ is the mesh spacing near $x=0$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: I think `NDSolve` can produce a solution only in the form of an `InterpolatingFunction`, and `InterpolatingFunction` can have as a domain, a tensor-product grid, a finite element mesh, or a product of the two (the product may be constrained to a one-dimensional grid for "time" by an element mesh for "space"). So while one could program the idea you propose, I don't think you can use `NDSolve` by itself to accomplish it.

Comment: OTOH, you might be able to have `NDSolve` do the time-stepping using the [plug-in framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html). It would probably take some work, which I don't have time to do (sorry). But a time-integration method can store and alter data (for instance, a mesh) at each step, which is basically your plan. You could `Sow[]` the solution vectors at each step and recover them with `Reap[]`. You would have to pass a solution `"StepOutput"` back to `NDSolve`. Not sure what to suggest for that.

Comment: Are you simulating a liquid film under the influence of surface tension and Van der Waal's force?

Comment: @dearN correct, this equation can describe such a liquid film and can be solved easily with `NDSolve`, as you know. Well, could you give some suggestions on how to get a more accurate solution near the singular behavior? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user95273 Singularities are typically difficult to accurately resolve.  Thinking about this physically, won't it be far more useful to identify when the film enters the catastrophic/rupture regime?  The time-scale at which rupture occurs can be sub-microsecond.  I am curious to know what is the value of capturing the film profile itself when you know that catastrophic phenomena has begun?

Comment: Try this notebook from our work from 2010. https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7891/

Comment: @dearN thanks for the useful link. I have tried it. Yes, a straightforward coding can resolve the singular behavior up to hmin~10^{-3}, especially the singular time. But the local profile cannot be accurately tracked further. Thus, I am interested in the numerical analysis aspect of this kind of equation using a variable mesh. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks a lot! I have limited knowledge about Mathematica and have read the content you suggested. Your idea appears promising but the abundant links and advanced techniques are daunting. I will appreciate it very much if you could help when you have time.

Answer (score 3):

This is hard (if not impossible) to achieve inside `NDSolve` AFAIK. I sincerely hope I'm wrong. As mentioned in the tutorial [The Numerical Method of Lines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html), particularly in *Spatial Error Estimates* section:

> Ideally, the spatial error estimates would be monitored over time and the spatial mesh updated according to the evolution of the solution. The problem of grid adaptivity is difficult enough for a specific type of PDE and certainly has not been solved in any general way. Furthermore, techniques such as local refinement can be problematic with the method of lines since changing the number of mesh points requires a complete restart of the ODE methods. There are moving mesh techniques that appear promising for this approach, but at this point, NDSolve uses a static grid.

The tutorial above is about `TensorProductGrid` method. As to `FiniteElement`, as mentioned by user21 [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/191546/1871):

> No, adaptive mesh refinement is not implemented in version 11.3 for PDE solving with the FEM. NIntegrate with the FEM uses an adaptive mesh refinement.

Additionally, your PDE is 4th order in $x$ direction, while currently `FiniteElement` method [doesn't support PDE whose spatial derivative order exceeds 2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199369/1871).

Comment: thank you very much for the information! So it is hopeless to solve this equation using NDSolve... Since NDSolve uses a static grid, if I use "MinPoints" -> 1000, "MaxPoints" -> 2000 in the method option, will it choose a fixed value between 1000 and 2000 as actual number of points according to a prior error estimate?

Comment: @user95273 Yes, exactly.